# Dealing with exception handling and re-queueing in RQ on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, queue, redis

I have a website running on Heroku in Python, and I have a worker up as a background process to handle tasks that I don't want to block webpage delivery and therefore are inappropriate for the `web` dynos.  For this, I've set up a queue using [`rq`](http://python-rq.org/) and redis.

In my process, occasionally, custom exceptions might arise.  For a specific subset of these, rather than allow the job to go straight to the 'failed' queue, I want to requeue it a few times.  I've been looking at the [exception handlers page](http://python-rq.org/docs/exceptions/) on the `rq` homepage, and I'm unclear on a few things.  In particular, it describes the following way to write an exception handler:

```
def my_handler(job, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    # do custom things here
    # for example, write the exception info to a DB
    ...
```

Right now, I'm planning to do something along the lines of:

```
   from rq import requeue_job
   def my_handler(job, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if exec_type == "MyCustomError":
           job.meta['MyErrorCount'] += 1
           job.save()

           if job.meta['MyErrorCount'] >= 10:
               return True
           else:
               requeue_job(job.id)
               return False
```

**Questions:**

- What kinds of objects are `exc_type`, `exc_value`, and `traceback`?  (*e.g.*, is the line `if exec_type == "MyCustomError"` at all correct?)
- Will my error handler effectively detect if it's a specific error, requeue those jobs until it fails 10 times, and then let it fall to `failed`?  Will it also let all other errors fall to `failed`?

Comment: No, this isn't the real code, it's a sanitized and simplified version for SO.  If you are pointing out that that line is completely incorrect, well, that is exactly the reason why I posted this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here’s my solution](https://gist.github.com/jokull/5498543)

```
queues = []

def retry_handler(job, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    # Returning True moves the job to the failed queue (or continue to
    # the next handler)

    job.meta.setdefault('failures', 1)
    job.meta['failures'] += 1
    if job.meta['failures'] > 3 or isinstance(exc_type, (LookupError, CorruptImageError)):
        job.save()
        return True

    job.status = Status.QUEUED
    for queue_ in queues:
        if queue_.name == job.origin:
            queue_.enqueue_job(job, timeout=job.timeout)
            break
    else:
        return True  # Queue has disappeared, fail job

    return False  # Job is handled. Stop the handler chain.

queues.append(Queue(exc_handler=retry_handler))
```

I decided to retry all errors three times unless a certain known exception type was encountered. This allows me to respect failures that are understood, like if a user was deleted after the job was created but before the job was executed, or in the case of an image resize job the image provided is no longer found (HTTP 404) or not in a readable format (basically whenever I know the code will never handle the job).

To answer your question: exc_type is the class, exc_value is the exception instance. `traceback` is useful for logging. If you care about this, check out Sentry. Workers are automatically configured with a Sentry error handler if run with `SENTRY_DSN` in the context. Much cleaner than polluting your own db with error logs.

Comment: Why do you have to cycle through the queues list?

Comment: I think you want to sub 

`for queue_ in queues:`

to `for queue_ in Queue.all(connection=StrictRedis())`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer shared by Jökull [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16326962/6212082) is on the correct lines just that the answer (and the post) is quite old. I had a similar situation where I needed to put retry logic in my redis-queue whenever a job fails. Here is a snippet for queue workers (had to move the logic to workers) taking inspiration from Jökull's answer (and comments), [redis-queue docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/) and [this](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-implementing-a-redis-task-queue/):

```
from rq import Worker, Connection, Queue
from redis import Redis
from app.config import Config

conn = Redis()
max_retries = 3

def retry_handler(job, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    # Returning True moves the job to the failed queue (or continue to
    # the next handler)
    job.meta.setdefault('failures', 1)
    job.meta['failures'] += 1
    if job.meta['failures'] > max_retries:
        job.save()
        return True
    # I was unable to locate Status in rq so added the status 'queued' that rq actually expects
    job.status = 'queued' 
    for queue_ in Queue.all(connection=conn):
        if queue_.name == job.origin:
            # at_front=True enqueues the job at the front of the queue for immediate retry.
            queue_.enqueue_job(job, at_front=True) 
            break
    else:
        return True  # Queue has disappeared, fail job

    return False  # Job is handled. Stop the handler chain.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Connection(conn):
            worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, ['your_queue_name'])), exception_handlers=[retry_handler])
            worker.work()
```

Answer (score -2):

1. for more info, read the doc of [sys](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).
2. 

> False means stop processing exceptions, True means continue and fall through to the next exception handler on the stack
>   
>   multiple exception handlers of the same job, `type` is exception type (a class), you should correct your code, other errors will return `None` interpreted as `True` as the rq doc says.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing me to `sys.exc_info()`, which provided some useful information.  Other than that link, however, I find this answer incomprehensible.